# clearUserPref not deleting pref from default branch

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In my add-on I added a pref to a branch that is not owned by me (its one of another addon, and in another case its one of firefox's branches). I also set a default value for it by setting its value on the default branch. How to delete just this one pref from that branch?

The only way I know how to delete a pref with default value set on it, is to delete the default branch. But this is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let prefs = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].
                getService(Ci.nsIPrefService).
                prefService.getDefaultBranch(null);

prefs.deleteBranch("full.pref.name")
```

Comment: Ohh genius! Thank you man! Take the all the way to the pref and treat it as a branch!

Comment: Thanks for updating from that `require("sdk/preferences/service").reset("full.pref.name")` yea im not sdk :P bootstrap all the way for me!

Comment: Instead of doing the `let = ....` could we just do `Services.prefs.deleteBranch('full.pref.name')`? Or is it more efficient to it your way if im going to be deleting more than one? Or does `Services.prefs.deleteBranch` only act on the non-default branch?

Comment: update: i think problem with this method is it doesnt just delete the default value, it deletes the pref from regular branch as well :(